# How to reverse angular script order injection with gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, development-environment, gulp-inject

I have the following scripts on my angular page when I build using `gulp watch-dev` (`gulpfile.js` is at the end of the question in the snippet).

```
<!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="shared/toolbar/toolbarDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/sidebar/sidebarDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/sidebar/sidbarController.js"></script>
  <script src="components/home/homeService.js"></script>
  <script src="components/blog/blogService.js"></script>
  <script src="components/blog/blogController.js"></script>
  <script src="app.modules.js"></script>
  <script src="app.routes.js"></script>
<!-- endinject -->
```

I want to get `app.modules.js` on top of others scripts. How can I do this ?

this is the files structure :

```
app
|
|--shared
|  |--sidebar
|  |  |--sidebarController.js
|  |  |--sidebarDirective.js
|  |  |--sidebarTemplate.html
|  |
|  |--toolbar
|     |--toolDirective.js
|     |--toolbarTemplate.html
|
|--components
|  |--home
|  |  |--sidebarDirective.js
|  |  |--homeView.html
|  |
|  |--blog
|     |--sidebarDirective.js
|     |--blogView.html
|
|--app.modules.js
|--app.routes.js
|--index.html
```

This where I think things fails :

```
pipes.orderedAppScripts = function() {
  return plugins.angularFilesort();
};

pipes.builtIndexDev = function() {

// sends verified vendor js in dev folder and catch a pipe ordered
var orderedVendorScripts = pipes.builtVendorScriptsDev()
    .pipe(pipes.orderedVendorScripts());

// sends verified app js in dev folder and catch a pipe ordered
var orderedAppScripts = pipes.builtAppScriptsDev()
    .pipe(pipes.orderedAppScripts());

var appStyles = pipes.builtStylesDev();

return pipes.validatedIndex()
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev)) // write first to get relative path for inject
    .pipe(plugins.inject(orderedVendorScripts, {relative: true, name: 'bower'}))
    .pipe(plugins.inject(orderedAppScripts, {relative: true}))
    .pipe(plugins.inject(appStyles, {relative: true}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.distDev));
 };
```

`buildIndexDev` is called in `watch-dev` to build index.html for development environment.
Here is my `gulpfile.js` in the snippet:

```html
<script src="https://gist.github.com/aemb/43ca3dbc7056157f952d.js"></script>
```

---

@HenryZou , doing this have some side effects:

```
   pipes.orderedAppScripts = function() {
     return gulp.src([
       './**/*.modules.js',
       './**/*.js',
     ]).pipe(plugins.angularFilesort());
   };
```

Weird thing here :

```
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <script src="shared/toolbar/toolbarDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="../distDev/gulpfile.js"></script>
  <script src="../distDev/distDev/app.modules.js"></script>
  <script src="../distDev/app.routes.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/sidebar/sidebarDirective.js"></script>
  <script src="../devServer/routes.js"></script>
  <script src="shared/sidebar/sidebarController.js"></script>
  <script src="../app/app.routes.js"></script>
  <script src="../server.js"></script>
  <script src="components/home/homeService.js"></script>
  <script src="../gulpfile.js"></script>
  <script src="components/blog/blogService.js"></script>
  <script src="components/blog/blogController.js"></script>
  <script src="app.routes.js"></script>
  <script src="app.modules.js"></script>
  <script src="../distDev/app/app.modules.js"></script>
  <script src="../distDev/app.modules.js"></script>
  <script src="../app/app.modules.js"></script>
  <!-- endinject -->
```

All those starting with `../` don't exist in the folder. Others exist but they are still in bad order.

Comment: can you make sure to put just the relevant part of code, rather than just dumping the whole thing

Comment: Thanks man! I didn't realize that I had accidentally cut that part while editing.

Comment: use *.modules.js instead of *.module.js

Comment: It's even more weird .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your gulp build script where you are globbing the files, specify your *.module.js prior to other *.js files.

```
   gulp.src([
        '/**/*.modules.js',
        '/**/*.js',
        ]).pipe(ngFilesort()),
```

Answer (score 0):

use gulp package gulp-html-replace to order the js declarations

More details

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-html-replace

**EDIT** gulp-html-replace comes with a great help if you want minified/concatenated js files. Using concatenation, you can segregate vendor js and custom js files I have not tried to use it with gulp-inject ,
may be this can help
Controlling what to be injected in order through gulp-html-replace

```
gulp.task('htmlwrite', function() {
  gulp.src('index.html')
    .pipe(htmlreplace({
        'vendorjs': ['vendor.min.js','common.js'], // naming the js for the ordring, multiple files can be added using array 
        'mainjs': 'main.min.js'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

and in the index.html

```
<!-- build:vendorjs -->
//includes the vendor js declaration
      <!-- endbuild -->

 <!-- build:mainjs -->

    <!-- endbuild -->
```

You can also go with **gulp-usemin**, seems it can solve your problem uses similar js injection like gulp-html-replace

Comment: I don't see how see can suit automation as I add more and more links to the development process. It can work if I know what is injected first in `index.html`. If I add more It will fails multiples times in process. I still have more scripts to add to the project. The process have to see them as dynamic elements.

Comment: You can control what to be injected first , see the edit

Comment: This looks more robust than using `gulp-print` weird bug. I will try it and validate your answer if it also works.
For those who struggle with this problem, just try ordering after gulp-file-sort process. If you do it before it will break. gulp-inject doesn't seems to support pipe ques or restored pipes and need full pipes. This is maybe the solution. I will review it tomorrow.

`gulp-file-sort`-->**modifications here**-->`gulp-inject`

Answer (score 0):

Don't ask me why it works. gulp-print does a weird thing that it's not supposed to do (very handy).

I did the following function to see pipes output :

```
var plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

pipes.testingShit = function() {
  return plugins.print(function(filepath) {
    return "built: " + filepath;
  });
};
```

Then I modified the following function to debug and there you have the miracle.

*from*:

```
pipes.orderedAppScripts = function() {
  return plugins.angularFilesort();
};
```

*to*:

```
pipes.orderedAppScripts = function() {
  return pipes.testingShit(plugins.angularFilesort());
};
```

The plugin `gulp-print` that is supposed to print in terminal the output for a reason I don't know is reversing the pipe. This is a weird thing that I can't explain for now.